# Is there a comparison between different blockchain.info's wallets?

Tags: blockchain.info

Blockchain.info has different ways to access their wallet, and I'd like to read a comparison of these different apps, especially concerning their security.

**I** am mostly interested in a **comparison between the [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blockchain/glaohkkooicollgefkkmndjcbblominl) and the [OSX app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/blockchain/id688882038?mt=12)**. There also are an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain.android), an [iOS app](https://blockchain.info/wallet/iphone-app) a [Firefox app](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/my-wallet/), not sure if there is something else too (likely something for Windows exists). There is of course the possibility to directly use the website too, but I assume this is almost always less secure than the rest, so there's not much point considering it (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: And why on Earth did this receive a close vote? O_o
Somebody practicing clicking random buttons, I guess...

Comment: no comment on the vote itself but you have enough reputation that you can select the 'close(1)' link to see: "Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."